# error while running keras from R in linux

Tags: python, r, linux, tensorflow, keras

I installed `keras` r package in linux. Then tried:

```
library(keras)
install_keras()
```

> Error: Prerequisites for installing TensorFlow not available.
>   Please install the following Python packages before proceeding: pip, virtualenv

Then I installed `pip` and `virtual env` in linux using:

```
sudo yum install python-pip
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

Then again I tried `install_keras()` and got following error:

```
Creating virtualenv for TensorFlow at  ~/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.10.1', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 299, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2228, in load_entry_point
    raise ImportError("Entry point %r not found" % ((group,name),))
```

> ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'virtualenv') not found
>   Error: Error 1 occurred creating virtualenv at ~/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow

How this problem can be solved?

Comment: When you run `sudo pip install virtualenv` you're running that command as root. What happens if you install virtualenv normally and then `install_keras()`?

Comment: It says permission denied if I don't run it as root.

Answer (score 0):

I used this on a debian machine and worked fine

> sudo apt-get install python-pip python-virualenv